# Go To Definition - getting back again

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

I am looking for a simple means of jumping back from a Go To Definition action, which goes directly back to the point from which I made the GTD jump.

The problem with the current workbench.action.navigateBack feature is that it revisits other locations over which I have moved the cursor (after making the GTD jump) before returning me to the point where I started. For instance:

```
  public takeoff() {
      this.landing();
  }

  public landing() {
    let x = 1;
    let y = 2;
      ...
      ...
  }
```

If I choose Go To Definition to move from takeoff() to landing() and then move the cursor up and down the lines of code in landing(), when I issue the **workbench.action.navigateBack** I simply want to return to takeoff(), but instead I have to revisit various lines within landing() along the way. Aaargh!

Do you know how to achieve the functionality which I am looking for?